# How can i make local http request in flutter?

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, dart, laravel-5

when i make access on website on endpoint "http://localhost/newsapp_api/public/api/authors"it's work without any problem,but when i try this in flutter it shows me a problem.
message error:E/flutter (24506): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 46873
codes:

**authors_api.dart**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:news_app/utilities/api_utilities.dart';

import 'package:news_app/models/author.dart';

class AuthorsAPI {

  Future<List<Author>> fetchAllAuthors() async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    List<Author> authors = List<Author>();
    String allAuthorsApi = base_api + all_authors_api;
    var url = Uri.parse(allAuthorsApi);

    var response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print("*****************");
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

**api_utilities.dart**

```
String base_api = "http://localhost/newsapp_api/public/api/authors";
String all_authors_api = "/api/authors";
```

Comment: Where did the port 46873 come from?  Are you sure that error is coming from this code?

Comment: i don't know from where come this error

Comment: When you get the exception, what is the stack trace?  Does it refer to this code?

Comment: how can i get stack trace?

Comment: i'm not use emulator ,i'm run app on mobile phone 
can i use ip mobile phone instead of127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

- make sure that you are not using any VPN or proxy server
- try to use http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost

hope this solve your problem

Comment: The link will become: http://127.0.0.1
  /newsapp_api/public/api/authors???

Comment: yes it will be http://127.0.0.1/newsapp_api/public/api/authors or try Patrick O'Hara ip also for emulator http://10.0.0.2/newsapp_api/public/api/authors

Comment: i'm not use emulator ,i'm run app on mobile phone

Comment: can i use ip mobile phone instead from 127.0.0.1

Comment: it depends on what is your back-end environment and how you published your server on your local network

Answer (score 0):

Note that `localhost` does not work with the Android emulator which uses `10.0.0.2`
To support both Web and Android emulator use the (local) IP address of the server

Comment: The link will become: http://10.0.0.2/newsapp_api/public/api/authors???

Comment: i'm not use emulator ,i'm run app on my mobile phone ,,
can i use ip mobile phone instead of127.0.0.1

Comment: I do not understand. The IP address is for the server that is serving your API. This will not be your phone. When testing your development machine is the server. When you run the app on an emulator it uses 10.0.0.2 to connect to the (local) server. If you are running the app on a real device, then it must use the actual IP of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the server running on `localhost` avalible on your device like this:
`adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`

Please note that you should replace 3000 with the port that you srever is running on.

And that's it! Now you can access `localhost` from your device.