# Cannot post data using getx in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to implement the login functionality in my flutter app using Getx.
The problem is that it's always getting the api endpoint in a wrong way, an error I have never faced before and it's just strange. Here is the response when I execute the function:

```
I/flutter ( 6456): Response: <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 6456): <html lang="en">
I/flutter ( 6456): <head>
I/flutter ( 6456): <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter ( 6456): <title>Error</title>
I/flutter ( 6456): </head>
I/flutter ( 6456): <body>
I/flutter ( 6456): <pre>Cannot POST /http:/localhost:4000/admin/user/login</pre>
I/flutter ( 6456): </body>
I/flutter ( 6456): </html>
```

Here is my api client class method:

```
const String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:4000";

Future<Response> postData(String endpoint, dynamic body) async {
    final url = '$BASE_URL/$endpoint';
    print(body.toString());
    try {
      Response response = await post(url, body, headers: _mainHeaders);
      print('Response: ' + response.body.toString());
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: ${e.toString()}');
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

And this is code from my auth repo:

```
  Future<Response> login(String email, String password) async {
    return await apiClient
        .postData("/admin/user/login", {"email": email, "password": password});
  }
```

Noting that the backend works perfectly and tested with postman as well, I don't know why it is reading the url as: `"/http:/localhost:4000/admin/user/login"` and not the way i'm passing it.

Edit:
dependencies file code:

```
Future<void> init() async {
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Get.lazyPut(() => sharedPreferences);

  //Api client
  Get.lazyPut(() => ApiClient(appBaseUrl: "http://51.77.230.230:4001/server/"));
  Get.lazyPut(
      () => AuthRepo(apiClient: Get.find(), sharedPreferences: Get.find()));

  //Repos
  Get.lazyPut(() => CategoriesRepo(apiClient: Get.find()));
  Get.lazyPut(() => ProductsRepo(apiClient: Get.find()));
  Get.lazyPut(() => CartRepo(sharedPreferences: Get.find()));
  Get.lazyPut(() => SubCategoriesRepo(apiClient: Get.find()));

  //Controllers
  Get.lazyPut(() => CategoriesController(categoriesRepo: Get.find()));
  Get.lazyPut(() => ProductsController(productsRepo: Get.find()), fenix: true);
  Get.lazyPut(() => CartController(cartRepo: Get.find()), fenix: true);
  Get.lazyPut(() => SubCategoriesController(subCategoriesRepo: Get.find()),
      fenix: true);
  Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(authRepo: Get.find()));
}
```

Comment: check this i think this may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796000/how-can-i-make-local-http-request-in-flutter

Comment: Actually no, I tried setting it as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but still the same issue

Comment: your app is running in which simulator or device  and in which platform?

Comment: I tried running it from the emulator and on a real device, using 127.0.0.1 and my local ipv4! all gave the same issue

Comment: you added in android manifest file internet permission & android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  this key ? because Flutter terms http as an insecure source

Comment: Of course, actually my get requests work pretty fine and I get the data, but post request did not work

Comment: any status code you getting response object for post method ?. remove try catch & print status code from response object check its status code which may help you to resolve your error.

Comment: status code is 404, I added code from my dependencies file

Comment: it means API call not found. check post url in code & compare postman url it may be different.